# Resolution of multiple equations (with exponential)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I would like to automatise the resolution of this kind of equations :

`a*exp(-b*90)=33`

`a*exp(-b*92)=66`

I first tried this with one equation and it worked:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import solveset, S
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import Symbol

a = symbols('a')
eq=sym.Eq(sym.exp(a*90),33)
solveset(eq,a,domain=S.Reals)
```

Then I tried this but it didn’t work :

```
a,b = symbols('a,b')
eq1 = sym.Eq(a*sym.exp(-b*90),33)
eq2 = sym.Eq(a*sym.exp(-b*92),66)
result=sym.solveset([eq1,eq2],(a,b),domain=S.Reals)
```

I get this error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [59], in <cell line: 9>()
      7 eq1 = sym.Eq(a*sym.exp(-b*90),33)
      8 eq2 = sym.Eq(a*sym.exp(-b*92),66)
----> 9 result=sym.solveset([eq1,eq2],(a,b),domain=S.Reals)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:2178, in solveset(f, symbol, domain)
   2175     return S.EmptySet
   2177 if not isinstance(f, (Expr, Relational, Number)):
-> 2178     raise ValueError("%s is not a valid SymPy expression" % f)
   2180 if not isinstance(symbol, (Expr, Relational)) and  symbol is not None:
   2181     raise ValueError("%s is not a valid SymPy symbol" % (symbol,))

ValueError: [Eq(a*exp(-90*b), 33), Eq(a*exp(-92*b), 66)] is not a valid SymPy expression
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I could proceed? Maybe solveset is not the adapted function?

Also I tried :

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import symbols, nonlinsolve

a, b = symbols('a, b', real=True)
eq1 = sym.Eq(a*sym.exp(-b*90),33)
eq2 = sym.Eq(a*sym.exp(-b*92),66)

nonlinsolve([eq1,eq2],[a,b])
```

I get

```
{(NaN, NaN),(3390(2+)35184372088832, {(2+)+log(2⎯⎯√2)|||||∈ℤ}),(3318035184372088832, {2+log(2⎯⎯√2)|||||∈ℤ})}
```

However I want real solutions and if I solve if by hand, i get `a= 33*2**(-45)` and `b= -ln(2)/2`. I don't understand why I don't get this solution.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Are you sure the equations are correct?

Comment: I am checking again and again and I can't find any mistake

Comment: You should probably raise an issue with Sympy. See for example https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18449 and https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22051 . I double checked the equations and the real solutions you provide with `nonlinsolve()` and they do match.

Comment: Thank you @norok2 You mean you tried to solve the equation with nonlinsolve and you get the same solution that I computed? Or you also solved the equation by yourself? I think 
the solution with nonlinsolve is not real

Comment: @alice I tried to solve it myself, and got the same solution as you. I also plugged those solution in `nonlinsolve()`, e.g. `sym.nonlinsolve([eq1, sym.Eq(b, -sym.ln(2) / 2)], [a, b])` and verified I got `a = 33 / 2**45`. If I try `sym.nonlinsolve([eq1, eq2], [a, b])` I get the same solution as you.

Comment: @norok2 Thank you for your answer and for spending time on my problem. 

To check if the solution found manually belongs to the computed solution set I tried this :
'sol=nonlinsolve([eq1,eq2],[a,b]);sol_byhand=(33*2**(-45),-sym.log(2)/2);sol_byhand in sol'

The answer was False

Comment: I raised an issue with Sympy here https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24060

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nonlinsolve gives you all solutions and you are having difficulty extracting the real solutions. Someone else can suggestion how to handle the Set solutions. I would recommend converting your equation to linear form and solving those equations with `solve`:

```py
>>> var('a:d')
>>> eq = Eq(a*exp(-b*c), d)
>>> leq = (log(eq.lhs) - log(eq.rhs)).expand(force=True)
>>> e1 = leq.subs([(c,90),(d,33)]);e2 = leq.subs([(c,92),(d,66)])
>>> solve((e1,e2),(a,b))
[(33/35184372088832, -log(2)/2)]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer and your help. Indeed this may be a good option. Since I am only starting on my project, I will have to solve more and more complex equations and I would like to be able to solve it without linearising it (if possible). 

I tried 2 ways to extract the real solution from the set :

1) `sol=nonlinsolve([eq1,eq2],[a,b]) & sym.Reals**2` but it leads to `EmptySet`.
2) `sol_real=[(a,b) for (a,b) in sol if (np.imag(a)==0 and np.imag(b)==0)]
print (f"only real solution : {sol_real}")` but I get `only real solution : []`

Comment: I have tried to adapt this to a system of 3 equations: CAL_spO2=[     (92,33),     (90,66),     (85,100), ]  eq = sym.Eq(a*sym.exp(-b*x)+c, y) leq = (sym.log(eq.lhs) - sym.log(eq.rhs)).expand(force=True) print(eq.lhs) print(eq.rhs)  eq0=leq.subs([(x,CAL_spO2[0][0]),(y,CAL_spO2[0][1])]) eq1=leq.subs([(x,CAL_spO2[1][0]),(y,CAL_spO2[1][1])]) eq1=leq.subs([(x,CAL_spO2[2][0]),(y,CAL_spO2[2][1])])  print((eq0,eq1,eq2)) sol2=solve([eq0,eq1,eq2]) but didn't work (doesn't finish to compile). Any idea how I could proceed? (I also tried with nonlinsolve)

Comment: That additive `c` breaks the ability to mak this linear. But take time to solve it by hand with sympy-assist or look at the result of solving it with the `manual=True, check=False` flags. You will see that there is no solution for the parameters you have selected. If you replace the 100 with `d` and solve for `a,c,d` you will get a parametric solution in terms of `b`. (Suggestion: use loop comprehensions to make equations; what you showed above is missing a definition for eq2: `var('a:d x y');CAL_spO2=[ (92,33), (90,66), (85,d)]; sol2=solve([Eq(a*exp(-b*x)+c, y) for x,y in CAL_spO2],a,c,d)`.